Need Guidance on Implementing Stratified K-Fold for Sequence Labeling (NER) Dataset
I'm currently working on a Named Entity Recognition (NER) task and I'm looking to implement Stratified K-Fold cross-validation for my dataset. However, I'm struggling to find specific references or guidelines on how to perform this technique for sequence labeling tasks like NER.
In fact, I already trying to perform this but the process always resulting an error.
Here are the key points I'm interested in:

Stratified K-Fold for Sequence Labeling: I want to understand how to adapt the standard Stratified K-Fold cross-validation technique for sequence labeling tasks. In NER, each token in a sequence is labeled with a specific entity type (e.g., person, organization, location). How can I ensure that each fold in the cross-validation maintains the same distribution of entity types as the original dataset?

Handling Sequential Dependence: Since sequence labeling tasks have a sequential dependency between tokens, how should I ensure that this dependency is preserved during the cross-validation process? Should I shuffle the entire sequences or just the samples?

Existing References or Implementations: I've searched for resources or existing implementations that demonstrate how to apply Stratified K-Fold specifically to sequence labeling datasets, but I haven't found much relevant information. Are there any papers, articles, or code examples that address this topic directly?


Any guidance, references, or insights on how to implement Stratified K-Fold cross-validation for sequence labeling datasets like NER would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
